# Trying to deserialize Json in c#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

I am attempting to deserialize JSON in C# in a WCF web service and repackage it as a list. I am using JObject.Parse in Json.NET. Below is the code that I am using to call the web service, get the JSON and put it into a list.

```
String url = URL to a web service;
HttpWebRequest WebReqOpenPermits = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
WebReqOpenPermits.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
WebReqOpenPermits.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse WebRespOpenPermits = (HttpWebResponse)WebReqOpenPermits.GetResponse();

Stream jsonStream = WebRespOpenPermits.GetResponseStream();
List<routeOpenPermits> permitsList = new List<routeOpenPermits>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonStream))
{
   string line;
   routeOpenPermits routeValues = new routeOpenPermits();
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       JObject results = JObject.Parse(line);
       foreach (var result in results["GetOpenPermitsByIdResult"])
                {
                  routeValues.oAddress = (string)result["oAddress"];
                  routeValues.oDateIssued = (string)result["oDateIssued"];
                  routeValues.oPermit = (string)result["oPermit"];
                  permitsList.Add(routeValues);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code adds the correct amount of records to the list but only the data for the last record in the JSON string is added to the list. For example, if the JSON data contains 5 records, all are added to the list but the data in the list comes only from the fifth and last record in the JSON string. The data from the fifth record is repeated five times in the list.

What I am doing wrong? Is there a better way because I am open to finding a new method. I have searched for quite a while but have not been able to find a solution. Thank you for any help, examples, guidance or advice that can be sent my way. I am thoroughly frustrated with deserializing JSON.

Comment: Your variable routeValues is declared outside of your foreach loop. This means that you're changing the value of one object each time through the loop. By the time you get to the end all of the values are set to the last item in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the line:

`routeOpenPermits routeValues = new routeOpenPermits();`

into the inside of your `foreach` loop

Comment: Yes, thanks that did it. I fixed it soon after posting but just now logged back in to answer my own question. It was a "dumb human error". I had been staring so long at the code and focused on the Json aspect that I did not see my error. I was looking at some other code in a different project and immediately spotted what I did wrong.